# Open Facebook Forms using Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to open a form using Facebook SDK. Deployed the below code on **HTTPS** but giving error 'Cannot load URL; The domain of the URL isn't included in the app's domains....'

I have included the domain in *'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs'*
Please help.
Below is code:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: '{your-app-id}',
      version: 'v2.7' // or v2.1, v2.2, v2.3, ...
    });
    FB.ui({         
  account_id: '<ACCOUNT_ID>',
  display: 'popup',
  method: 'lead_gen',
  page_id: '<PAGE_ID>',
}, function(response) {
  // callback
});
  });
```

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: Version 'v3.1'.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the domain as a ‘Website URL’ under both ‘Add a Domain’ and ‘Add Product’  options on Facebook’s App page.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlhx7.jpg)
In our case, we are opening a Facebook’s Marketing API: Lead Gen (AKA Lead Ads), for which the redirection happens from a child domain. So the exact domain of the web page was expected at both the above places.
I have also observed that, HTTPS is not mandatory.
Thanks!